# Casting a column in a spark DataFrame without nulls being created

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Is there a way to cast columns in Spark and have it fail in case of a type mismatch rather than getting a null returned?

As an example I have a DF with all string columns but one of them I want to cast to date

```
+----------+------------+------------+
|   service|   eventType|process_date|
+----------+------------+------------+
| myservice| myeventtype|  2020-10-15|
| myservice| myeventtype|  2020-02-15|
|myservice2|myeventtype3|  notADate  |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

If I try to cast this with the main `cast` function `df.withColumn("process_date", df("process_date").cast(targetType))` it will replace the bad data with a `null`

```
+----------+------------+------------+
|   service|   eventType|process_date|
+----------+------------+------------+
| myservice| myeventtype|  2020-10-15|
| myservice| myeventtype|  2020-02-15|
|myservice2|myeventtype3|        null|
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Using this function in my current program could result in dangerous loss of data that I might not catch until it's too late.

Comment: Try using `coalesce` when you cast to date. Something like `coalesce(cast(process_date as date), to_date('0000-00-00'))`. This will default the process_date to `0000-00-00` whenever the cast returns `NULL`.

Comment: @philantrovert this is perhaps useful in some situations but I really want to get some runtime feedback when this issue occurs so I can handle it

Answer (score 0):

I find two ways of doing what you want.

First, if you really want the process to fail when a Date is not parseable you can use UDF:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType

object Data {
  val tuples = List(
    ("myservice", "myeventtype", "2020-10-15"),
    ("myservice", "myeventtype", "2020-02-15"),
    ("myservice2", "myeventtype3", "notADate")
  )
}

object BadDates {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val dfBad = Data.tuples.toDF("service","eventType","process_date")

    val dateConvertUdf = udf({str : String => java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse(str))})

    dfBad
      .withColumn("process_date", dateConvertUdf(col("process_date")))
      .show()
  }
}
```

This will fail with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(BadDates$$$Lambda$1122/934288610: (string) => date)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:156)
...
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'notADate' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
```

Alternatively you can do the conversion and check if the converted value is null but the original isn't for any line:

```
object BadDates2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val dfBad = Data.tuples.toDF("service","eventType","process_date")

    val df = dfBad
      .withColumn("process_date_dat", col("process_date").cast(DateType))

    val badLines = df
      .filter(col("process_date").isNotNull && col("process_date_dat").isNull)
      .count()

    assert(badLines==0) //This will fail, badLines is 1
  }
}
```